# Monomorphism into the subobject classifier of $\mathbf{Set}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

In the category of sets, is the unique morphism $0 \to \Omega$ a monomorphism?

Here $0$ is the initial object, i.e. $\emptyset$ and $\Omega = 2$ is the subobject classifier.

Here's my initial argument at the moment:

Denote the unique $0 \to \Omega$ by $f$. Then to show $f$ is mono is the same a showing $f$ is injective in $Set$, i.e. for all $a_1,a_2:1 \to 0$ we have that if $fa_1 =f a_2$ then $a_1 = a_2$.

Now since $0 \ncong 1$ in $Set$ the initial specification of $a_1, a_2$ is vacuous, since they don't exist. Therefore $f a_1 = f a_2 \Rightarrow a_1 = a_2$ is vacuously true. So $f$ is injective and therefore mono.

Comment: This argument is correct. There is nothing special about $\Omega$; any morphism out of the empty set is a monomorphism (i.e. is injective).